# How to work around updating polymer-cli on Ubuntu on Windows which fails due to .git: Permission denied

Tags: windows, git, ubuntu, polymer-2.x, polymer-cli

I need a workaround for updating polymer-cli on Ubuntu shell on Windows 10 which fails due to "...git: Permission denied".

I am following [this](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli) running an Administrator Ubuntu shell on Windows 10.

All is well until `$ sudo npm install -g polymer-cli` which yields:

```
npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone --depth=1 -q -b master git://github.com/polymerelements/test-fixture.git /home/<USERNAME>/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-fe296ee9
npm ERR! /home/<USERNAME>/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-fe296ee9/.git: Permission denied
```

I found [this npm issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11567) which may or may not be germane.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It looks like your global NPM installs to your local directory.  What happens if you omit `sudo`?

Comment: with NO sudo in Administrator shell:Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/@types/assert' ...  Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's causing this, but a workaround is to manually run the command and try again:

```
sudo /usr/bin/git clone --depth=1 -q -b master git://github.com/polymerelements/test-fixture.git /home/<USERNAME>/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-<HEX DIGITS FROM ERROR MESSAGE>
sudo npm install -g polymer-cli
```

Unfortunately, more permission issues occurred after this one. As such, I had to install `polymer-cli` in my app's local `node_modules` folder like so:

```
npm install polymer-cli
./node_modules/.bin/polymer --help
```

Answer (score -1):

try yarn.

yarn global add polymer-cli